# R Error: package load failed for ‘robustbase’. robustbase.so: undefined symbol: is_redescender

Tags: r, failed-installation, r-package

Installation of *robustbase* **failed** (R version **3.5.1**).
OS - **Scientific Linux** release 6.8 (Carbon).
The same problem was reported for **Ubuntu 18.04** on [R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6588&group_id=59&atid=302), and [for different compilers' flag](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6590&group_id=59&atid=302).

```
 > devtools::install_cran('robustbase', type = 'source', INSTALL_opts = '--byte-compile')
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/robustbase_0.93-1.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2957641 bytes (2.8 MB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 2.8 MB


Installing robustbase
Running /mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL \
  /tmp/RtmpkMixso/devtools1bf93b25b117/robustbase \
  '--library=/mnt/lustre/etretiakov/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5' \
  --install-tests 
* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c init.c -o init.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c lmrob.c -o lmrob.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c mc.c -o mc.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c monitor.c -o monitor.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c qn_sn.c -o qn_sn.o
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rf-common.f -o rf-common.o
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rffastmcd.f -o rffastmcd.o
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rfltsreg.f -o rfltsreg.o
f95   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rllarsbi.f -o rllarsbi.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c rob-utils.c -o rob-utils.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c rowMedians.c -o rowMedians.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -I"/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -I/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//include -I/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//include -I/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//include -I/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//include -I/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//include  -c wgt_himed.c -o wgt_himed.o
/mnt/lustre/tools/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc -shared -L/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/lib -L/home/tools/curl/curl-7.51.0//lib -L/home/tools/pcre/pcre-8.39//lib -L/home/tools/xz/xz-5.2.2//lib -L/home/tools/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6//lib -L/home/tools/zlib/zlib-1.2.8//lib -o robustbase.so R-rng4ftn.o eigen.o init.o lmrob.o mc.o monitor.o qn_sn.o rf-common.o rffastmcd.o rfltsreg.o rllarsbi.o rob-utils.o rowMedians.o wgt_himed.o -L/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 -lgfortran -lm -L/mnt/lustre/tools/R/R-3.5.1/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /mnt/lustre/etretiakov/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/robustbase/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** tests
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function from function ‘chgDefaults’ in package ‘robustbase’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘robustbase’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/mnt/lustre/etretiakov/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/robustbase/libs/robustbase.so':
  /mnt/lustre/etretiakov/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/robustbase/libs/robustbase.so: undefined symbol: is_redescender
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/mnt/lustre/etretiakov/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/robustbase’
Error in run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),  : 
  System command error
```

Attempts to use **other compilers** were followed by the **same problem**.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: @Prateek Format's improved now.

Comment: Did you try the work around in the first bug report?

Comment: Yes, a solution of Martin Maechler is correct.
1. unpack robustbase_0.93-1.tar.gz
2. change line 62 of robustbase/src/robustbase.h from inline to static inline